# Open tracking for long emails isn't triggered in Gmail as the tracking image is at the bottom of the message

Tags: civimail, mosaico, flexmailer

With Mosaico templates, it isn't that difficult to reach Gmail's limit of 102kB with an email newsletter, after which your email message is clipped and not displayed in full. This is unfortunate in itself, but it also breaks open tracking as the tracking pixel is only embedded at the very end of the message and thus isn't fetched unless you open the reader clicks "View entire message".

Would it risk too much ugliness for those who don't display images to put the tracking pixel at the start of the message?

Comment: Lars: I think that’s a good idea!

Comment: This seems like an interesting proposal but I don't think it really suits the format of StackExchange. It might be better to propose it in GitLab instead: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues

Comment: Added this as in issue on Flexmailer, as I believe this is the relevant place: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.flexmailer/issues/64

Comment: Just in case this is useful to someone in the future, the Gmail 102Kb limit is perhaps a little fuzzier than exactly 102Kb. Seems something more like 96Kb (or 99Kb on disk) is safer.
I had two emails that had the same subject, sent at the same time, one was 96.5Kb and one was 97.5Kb. Similar open rates for all domains except gmail.com, where the slightly longer email had a roughly one third lower open rate (relative to the other email and relative to other email addresses receiving the same email). So Gmail is cutting off the email at slightly different points for different people, it seems.

Comment: Just noting for housekeeping that flexmailer has moved into core now and that it's possible  issue/64 was not moved across.

Comment: There is an open issue. I'm not entirely sure what the right solution is here and will need to do some more research to find out what others are doing for this - we don't want to cause other issues for the vast majority of emails that aren't hitting that limit
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3616